# What is the authentication period for Firebase Authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to know what the default authentication period for users to be logged into Firebase is. I have an Android app where users are logging in via email/password and I want to know how long `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` will remain not null.

In the previous version of Firebase, the default length of time was 24 hours and could be modified via the firebase console.  Is the default amount of time still 24 hours?  Can this be modified via the console?  (I cannot seem to find anything regarding this in the latest version of Firebase)

Comment: Dont know the amount before you will be automatically logged out. But what i do know is that the token will be refreshed

Comment: It will automatically handle refreshing the token for you?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users
"The access token expires: this is a common situation. The refresh token is used to get a new valid set of tokens."
Also noted that myself on my own app. Never got logged out. But i use my app every day. So never seen it expire

Comment: That is a really good point.  Thanks for sharing this link!  Can you add it as an answer so I can mark it as correct for the time being.  This is more than likely the right answer based upon the information you shared with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this question is six years old at this point, but as mentioned in the comments, [the user lifecycle](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#the_user_lifecycle) states that the user token will expire and that in that event, the refresh token will be used to automatically reissue a set of new tokens for the user when using the SDKs. This allows the user to continue using the app without issue and does not force the user to re-authenticate into the app when their session token has expired.